# How do I create and run the custom database?

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

When I created my pet site and visiting it. I noticed money systems and pet systems all need database for them. But I'm wondering is there any way to create new rows for money system? I need money system for that to purchase virtual pets and itens.
So is there any codes when i click on a thing in the site that adds or removes from database date? Thank you a lot!

I thought that follows that code before I know DB:

```
<?php

$coin=50;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no 'magic buttons' working out of the box - you can get that kind of button but you need to create DB structure, connection, write proper functions/methods (depends on your coding approach) and then bind it to that button.

Even if you are going to use some package/plugin or whatever you find useful - you need to have configured DB to be able to use that.

It is even hard to send you some links with examples/documentation as you did not give any kind of information regarding what (I guess) CMS or service you are using.

Deliver more info and then there is a chance that someone will be able to help.

Comment: i noticed at all. i've found it before